# How can I show part of an element, and toggle to all of the element on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm aware how to use `slideDown()` to display an element that was previously hidden.

But how can I do this for a single element?  That is, not toggling a hidden element, but instead growing the visible window of a fluid height element?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PzA5D/

Here's some HTML markup:

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400&text=long+img">
</div>
<button class="btn">View More</button>
```

And CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And JS:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.mydiv').slideDown();
});
```

Note, I know my example has a fixed height, but assume the image can be any height.  But no matter what the height, only the first 100px will be shown until "View More" is clicked.

**UPDATE**

I'd prefer to keep the slidedown-style animation if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/TUMR2/2)</kbd>

```
var mydiv = $('.mydiv');
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mydiv.animate({
        height: mydiv.find('img').height()
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This accomplishes the question, although without the nice animation that `slidedown()` provides. Is there a way to animate toward that end?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $div = $('.mydiv')
    $div.animate({
        'height': $div.prop('scrollHeight')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8X8ax/)

Comment: Yes. But is there a way to animate toward that end?

Comment: Thanks. This gets me closer. If I put another div inside I can get it to work with flexible content types. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8X8ax/5/ Any way to accomplish this without extra markup? Assuming the `.mydiv` is filled with an assortment of divs and images and the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to slide Up and Down but not hide completely, you need to use `animate()`

http://jsfiddle.net/PzA5D/2/

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.mydiv').height() < "210") {
        $('.mydiv').animate({height: $('.mydiv .wrapper').height() + 'px'}, 1000);
    } else {
        $('.mydiv').animate({height: '205px'}, 1000);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Included is a `.wrapper` div so that there could be anything inside it, not just an image, and the animation will still work.

Comment: This seems like it could do the trick.  But if my content isn't an image, but instead just fluid length text, or an assortment of other divs, then how can I get the appropriate height to animate to? I tried `.outerHeight()` but that just returns the initial min-height set in the CSS instead of the full height that's partly hidden.

Comment: It would be nice if you could simply use 100%, but unfortunately you can't, `animate()` fails. You would have to have a wrapper div inside that has the full height of whatever your contents are, which is being clipped by the `overflow: hidden;` of `.mydiv`. Answer updated. http://jsfiddle.net/PzA5D/3/ example if it were just text, no image.